# How to create XML signatures for Photoshop Extension

Tags: xml, plugins, adobe, photoshop, signatures

I created new Photoshop Panel and I use the [PS-installer](https://github.com/undavide/PS-Installer) to install my extension.

However, I must create the signatures.xml to properly run my panel, but I don't know how do it.

> The extension could not be loaded because it was not properly signed.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Lukasz

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1) Just Disabled the libraries panel from Window > Libraries and the error will go away

Solution 2) If you don't want to disable then just reinstalle it with a fresh copy of cc from prosesigntools.com. Make sure you uninstall properly.

Solution 3) Preference > plug in > disable - allow extension to connect internet

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need create signatures.xml, because I want to publish my Extension to download and easy install.